# Why is my GTA crew rank messing up?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

The crew rank I should be at is 'Channing Tatum', but it just says 'Enforcer'. I checked online and everything is good, but every time I level up it says: 'Crew Rank: Enforcer'.

Answer (score -2):

It is only for the website.My rank in my crew should be "Footlong Lover" (The crew leader is weird)But in game it is Enforcer.

Comment: This is confirmation of the problem, but it offers no answer or solution. You've answered more than 10 questions in the last hour, try slowing down a bit and focusing on quality over quantity.